# How to report AWS Amplify Console pipeline status to GitLab?

Tags: reactjs, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, create-react-app, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify to build and deploy a React application built with Create React App. The issue is that I could not find a way to report the build status to GitLab so that I can see the build status for a branch or a merge request.

Is there a way to integrate the build status seen in AWS Amplify Console into GitLab?